# Is there any way migrate postgresql db without pg_dump?

Tags: linux, postgresql, crash, database-backups

The original postgres server was run on ubuntu , but the machine crash and can't boot .

I tried to mount the disk on the Ubuntu live with the postgres installed , and then change the `data_directory` to the path of the oringinal data_directoty which I mount ,but it failed.
There is no error message when I run `systemctl start postgresql` ,but when I try to login with psql ,it show

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

It seem that the server is not on. How can I fix it ?

Or is there any other way to get the database without booting the original machine?

Comment: If you use the same database version, it should be able to recover from the original data_directory. And if it cannot, there will be error messages. You need to find out why that server failed to come up.

Comment: try `pg_ctl -D data_directory`?..

Comment: And take a full backup of that volume with the database on it before you do anything.

Comment: The log when I run `systemctl start postgresql` is `2018-05-11 07:53:45 UTC [29628-2] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2018-05-11 07:53:45 UTC [29633-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2018-05-11 07:53:45 UTC [29630-1] LOG:  shutting down
2018-05-11 07:53:45 UTC [29630-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
`

Comment: Check if the server is running (`ps -f -u postgres`).

Comment: It's running !! `postgres 30750 30749  0 08:40 pts/2    00:00:00 bash` ,but it can't login with psql as I say above

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem,

1. The privilege of data_directory should
   be 700 ,but I set to 777
   `sudo chmod -R <data_dir> 700`
2. The owner of data_directory should be postgres
   `sudo chown -R postgres:postgres <data_dir>`